# Changing numpy dimension order from i,j,k to k,i,j

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

i need help!

I created numpy array from nifti 3D image. 
Since dataset dimension order is provided as x,y,z (i,j,k), I need to change it to z,x,y (k,i,j).

Nifti image dimensions order is 512x512x508 (i,j,k) and after conversion to numpy array I am getting wrong shape, because it is seen as (k,i,j)

So I need to flip dimension order to get shape (512,512) and not (512,508).

I tried various versions of flip, fliplr, transponse, but I don't think I am getting anywhere...

How can I correctly flip this array?

````
a = np.load("/home/roman/train/processed_data/data_train.npy")
a[0].shape```
gives: 
(512, 508)
````

Comment: [`np.transpose(arr, (2, 0, 1))`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html)

Comment: numpy.rollaxis maybe ?

Comment: Yea I was trying np.transpose already , but now i realized I was doing it at wrong place in my code... I succesfully did it now. So thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

numpy einsum is a good tool to be used.
Official document: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html

```
nifti = np.random.randint(0,5,size=(508,512,513)) 
# set the last dim to 513 just to make stuff more clear
nifti.shape
# (508, 512, 513)

nifti_reshape = np.einsum('kij->ijk',nifti)
nifti_reshape.shape
(512, 513, 508)
```

In my opinion it's the most clear way to write and read.